# Mysql: How do I use WHERE condition with partitioning

Tags: mysql, where-clause

For example,
THERE are users who has read books with numbers below:

```
History (1002,1424,2512,4625,1245)
Art (1592,6413,5030,5362)
Fantasy (5929,5920,1245,2152)
```

And Users (a,b,c,d,e)

I want to know how to make mysql query with above criteria.
I want to know how many Users have read all the books in History or Art or Fantasy 
So one of users who has read all the books in History or Art or Fantasy, he should be contained.

```
SELECT
count(distinct Users) as User
FROM
table
WHERE
book_id in (1002,1424,2512,4625,1245) or
book_id in (1592,6413,5030,5362) or
book_id in (5929,5920,1246,2152)
```

And above query seems not containing all the books because I used 'in'.

so the table may be like this

```
user|    book_id    |      category
---------------------------------------
a   |      1002     |      History    
a   |      1424     |      History      
a   |      2512     |      History      
a   |      4625     |      History    
a   |      1245     |      History
a   |      2152     |      Fantasy
b   |      1592     |      Art
b   |      6413     |      Art
b   |      5030     |      Art
b   |      5362     |      Art
c   |      5929     |      Fantasy
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you add sample tables structure so we can better undersatand?

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani Oh I have added it!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS userscount
FROM sourcetable
WHERE book_id in (1002,1424,2512,4625,1245,1592,6413,5030,5362,5929,5920,1245,2152)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM( book_id in (1002,1424,2512,4625,1245) ) = 5
    OR SUM( book_id in (1592,6413,5030,5362) ) = 4
    OR SUM( book_id in (5929,5920,1245,2152) ) = 4
```

The query assumes that `(user_id, book_id)` is defined as UNIQUE.

Comment: Wow I may try it, Thank you so much!